# Swift: restore previous view controller after an unwind segue

Tags: ios, swift, segue, unwind-segue

I have two swift UI View Controllers:

```
class AViewController:UIViewController {
    [...]
    func OnBluetoothEventA() {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "BSegue", sender: self)
    }
    func OnBluetoothEventB() {
        // Go back to this viewcontroller!
    }
}

class BViewController:UIViewController {
    [...]
}
```

When user turn off bluetooth, I perform a segue to show an animation and a message.

When user turn bluetooth on, I want to restore the previous ViewControl.

Which is the best swift way to do it?

Comment: You can use KVO (key-value observer) for this purpose. Add observer when bluetooth is turned off then trigger a method in the firstViewController to go to secondViewController. And again in the secondViewController use another observer to observe when the bluetooth is turned on. Now google how to use KVO in swift.

Answer (score 0):

I made a new bluetooth manager inside BViewController, then I use dismiss:

```
extension ConnectAlertViewController: CBPeripheralManagerDelegate {
    // MARK: Bluetooth
    func peripheralManagerDidUpdateState(_ peripheral: CBPeripheralManager) {
        switch(peripheral.state) {
        case .poweredOn:
            self.dismiss(animated: true)
            break
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```